# how to click on an SVG toactivate a function in the parent webpage

Tags: javascript, html, svg

```js
function load_AnimalChosen(xxxx) {

 alert("in AnimalChosen");
   
 var s = document.getElementById("animal");
 s.textContent = "ANIMAL" ;
{
```

```css
/* Set height of body and the document to 100% */
 body, html {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     font-family: Arial;

  overflow:hidden;
 }


 iframe {
     height: 48%;
         padding: 2px 2px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>


<body>

  <iframe id="iFrame_5" src="animals.svg" width="100%" ></iframe>

  <p>the animal is a ...</p>
  <p id="animal">????</p>

</body>

</html>
```

I have a webpage with two tabs.

The first tab contains an SVG image - a cat and a dog.

The second tab is blank, but is to load information depending upon which animal is clicked in the SVG image on tab 1.

When I click on the cat this function in the SVG is activated to tell the webpage to load info about cats into Tab2.

xxxx is 1 for the cat

```
function loadAnimal(xxxx){

var chosen_value = xxxx;

window.parent.load_AnimalChosen(chosen_value);
}
```

The function load_AnimalChosen() in the Webpage does not get activated.

How should line 2 be written?

I am certain that this code worked in internet explorer and  firefox a few years ago. 
Then it only worked in firefox, not Edge. 
Now it doesn't work at all.

I was unable to load an svg into the code snippet. this is a suitable file.

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width = "100%" height = "100%" viewBox="0 0 540 328" >

  <script>
  <![CDATA[

  function loadAnimal(xxxx){

  var chosen_value = xxxx;

  alert("chosen_value " + chosen_value);

  window.parent.load_AnimalChosen(chosen_value);
  }

 ]]>
 </script>

    <text x="175" y="52" font-size="28" fill="blue" font-style="italic" font-  weight="bold"  text-anchor="middle" onclick="loadAnimal(1)" >CAT</text>
    <text x="175" y="152" font-size="28" fill="blue" font-style="italic" font-weight="bold"  text-anchor="middle" onclick="loadAnimal(2)" >DOG</text>

  </svg>
```

Comment: Are you using `<frameset>` and `<frame>` tags?

Comment: Please edit the question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: The SVG is in an iframe.

Comment: the function loadAnimal shown above is activated. An alert() before the window.parent....... line gives the correct value for the animal chosen. But an Alert()  in the parent document's function first line does not display.